# How to communicate with Oracle eBusiness suite from c/c++

Tags: c++, c, oracle

Please tell me if there is any sdk through which I can communicate Oracle eBusiness suite from c or cpp.  I know OCCI is for interacting with Oracle DB, i am looking a way to interact with Oracle ebusiness suite(payments)

Any help please

Thanks

Swathi

Answer (score 1):

Per the Oracle documentation:

- One approach is to use Pro*C Embedded SQL in conjunction with your favorite compiler:

  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18727_01/doc.121/e12897/T302934T458256.htm
- Another approach is to use web services with their SOA gateway:

  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18727_01/doc.121/e12169/T511175T543269.htm
- Here is a "Newbie's Guide" (not C++):

  http://www.oracleappshub.com/api/a-newbie%E2%80%99s-guide-to-e-business-suite-integration-by-custom-code-using-apis%E2%80%9D/
- You might also consider mashups (not C++):

  http://www.jackbe.com/enterprise-mashup/blog/mashing-oracle-part-3-mashing-oracle-e-business-suite-1
- Whatever you do, prepare to get your hands at least a little dirty with PL/SQL, and possibly some Java.